# Why am I seeing these characters instead of text in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Why am I seeing these characters instead of text in Firefox ?

It's a public site https://www.ratemds.com/

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Comment: Is not my site, not a development question, it's a public site https://www.ratemds.com/

Answer (score 1):

The reason why there those icons are not displayed is related to the **FontAwesome** that is used in **CSS**.

Firefox don't allow use of cross domain fonts.

**Solution**: change the location (hosting) for those external fonts.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand, it is not my site, its a public website, is there a setting in firefox that can fix that?

Comment: When I started to write this post, I thought that you were the developer of that site. Than I saw your comment and your edit. I answered only for your first question. I don't think that you can change Firefox to solve the problem without changing the website.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your firefox isn't set up to let sites use their own custom fonts.
This can become more and more prevalent these days with sites using many custom fonts for button icons. (See: "font awesome", or "bootstrap glyphicons")

You can try opening a blank firefox -> Settings -> Content -> "Fonts & Colors" -> Advanced -> Then look for the checkbox that reads "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above."  [image]

Once you've check that box, Firefox will allow the sites you visit to use their own custom fonts.  This should fix your issue, if it does not I did some additional research and was able to find a configuration setting that also causes this which I'll demonstrate as "Advanded Solution" below.

ADVANCED SOLUTION:

1. In the firefox address bar type "about:config" without the quotes
2. Select the button promising to be careful (and truly please do)
3. In the search type in "gfx" without the quotes
4. Find the item "gfx.downloadable_fonts.enabled" without the quotes
5. If the status is set to "user set" and the value is "false" then follow step 6
6. Right click the line item, and select "toggle" from the drop down options

[image]

If the first fix didn't work, the second fix should work.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Mike, unfortunately non of the methods helped. For the  "config" solution, I already had default-boolean-true for gfx.downloadable_fonts.enabled.